# ionic3 streaming-media in android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i have i problem i want to use plugin streaming-media in ionic3 
when i build projet i tested apk  have  blank page 
I followed all the steps inside website : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingAudioOptions  } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) {

  }
   startAudio() {
   let options: StreamingAudioOptions = {
      bgImage: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/large-glossy-icons/512/Sound.png',
      successCallback: () => { console.log('Finished Audio') },
      errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error: ', e) },
      initFullscreen: false // iOS only!
    };

     this.streamingMedia.playAudio('http://10.10.10.10:8000/;', options);
  }


}



  <button (click)="startAudio()" ion-button color="secondary" icon-end>
       Start Audio
      <ion-icon name="musical-notes"></ion-icon>
    </button>
```

please help me 
[image]
thank you

Comment: Any console errors.....?

Comment: Any errors when i build

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: when i run apk have blank page no audio streaming